# Why does Milkman's StoreKit AS3 API seem to crash on second call to create()?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I recently started using the Milkman StoreKit native extension for in-App purchasing on IOS. I initially found it great and seemed to get it up and running fairly swiftly, however I can't get around one issue.

If I try to call StoreKit.create() a second time it appears to crash. The first time its prefect… I get the product info from the iTunes store, the purchase goes through and my app updates as intended. Any second attempt to create Storekit and it gets stuck on the Storekite.create() line of code. I even made a new app just to test this (to eliminate any errors I many have made) and again, first create() no problem, second one crashes. Below is my code on the tester app I made (just on the timeline).

```
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.ios.*;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.ios.events.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;



function openStoreKit(e:MouseEvent):void {

var t:TraceOnStage = new TraceOnStage(stage,"startProcess" + StoreKit);

if (! StoreKit.isSupported()) {

    var t:TraceOnStage = new TraceOnStage(stage,"not supported" + StoreKit);

    return;
}

var t:TraceOnStage = new TraceOnStage(stage,"initialising" + StoreKit);

StoreKit.create();

var t:TraceOnStage = new TraceOnStage(stage,"initialised!");


}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, openStoreKit);
```

First call to openStoreKit() no problem.. I get "initialising[StoreKit]" in my trace out then "initalised". Second call just "initialising[StoreKit]" and crashes.

I have tried everything I can think of. I have recently updated to AIR 3.4 SDK, could it be to do with that? (I am using Flash Pro CS6)

Comment: Just in case it helps. TraceOnStage is a little class I made for tracing statements on the stage (good for testing on the iPad). I have used it for years and it definitely works! Also I am not implying the StoreKit API is at fault. I am sure it could be just how I am using it, however I read up a lot on it before I started using it.

Comment: OK I have worked it out. Just need to put StoreKit.create() inside a try - catch. It is a singleton so only one can exist.

Comment: That seems a bit weird for a singleton usually the first call to create should create the instance and store it in a static member and subsequent calls to create should just return that instance instead of crashing.

Comment: Yeah I have to admit that is what I thought too. I think I may be a bug when using the AIR SDK 3.3 and over as the documentation that comes with the extension package mentions nothing of this. Anyway CODE try { StoreKit.create() } catch(e:Error) { } END CODE works a treat.